# How can I deflate zlib data and find out how many input bytes there were?

Tags: git, rust, zlib

I'm building a git clone implementation in Rust. I've gotten to the part where I need to parse the packfile to create the index, and I'm almost done parsing it.

Each object in the packfile consists of a header (Which I'm already parsing correctly) followed by the contents which are zlib compressed.

Notably the size stored in the header is the *decompressed* size, and is therefore larger than the actual data we have to skip to get to the next header.

Crates.io shows 2 crates that do zlib decompression and have more than a few downloads:

- `libz-sys`: Is practically a hello world and has been like that for months
- `flate2`: This correctly deflates the data with ease:

  ```
  print!("Object type {} size {}", obj_type as u8, obj_size);

  println!(" data:\n{}",
      String::from_utf8(
          ZlibDecoder::new(data).read_exact(obj_size as usize).unwrap()
      ).unwrap()
  );
  ```

Here's the problem. After this I need to start reading the next object's header, but `ZlibDecoder` doesn't give any way to detect how large the *input* was.

It takes ownership of a reader as it's input, rather than a reference.

Because of this, even though I have the output size of the object (and indeed *all* the object's data) since I don't know the input size I can't start reading the next object header.

How do I get the amount of compressed input bytes needed to reach the expected output size? If possible, I'd like to avoid using FFI to call native zlib.

PS: the `flate2` docs suggest a [helper trait](http://alexcrichton.com/flate2-rs/flate2/trait.FlateReader.html) but I have no idea how or if this would help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you can pass a reference to a Reader / Writer (via [`ByRefReader`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/old_io/trait.ByRefReader.html) or [`ByRefWriter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/old_io/trait.ByRefWriter.html))  to allow adding adapters to the stream without losing control of it. Something like this *should* work:

```
#![feature(io,path,env)]

extern crate flate2;

use flate2::CompressionLevel;
use flate2::writer::ZlibEncoder;
use flate2::reader::ZlibDecoder;

use std::env;
use std::old_io::File;
use std::old_io::{ByRefReader,ByRefWriter};
use std::old_path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path = "./data";
    let write = env::var("WRITE").is_ok();

    if write {
        println!("Writing to {}", path);
        let mut f = File::create(&Path::new(path)).unwrap();

        fn write_it<W>(w: &mut W, s: &str) where W: Writer {
            let mut z = ZlibEncoder::new(ByRefWriter::by_ref(w), CompressionLevel::Default);
            z.write_all(s.as_bytes()).unwrap();
        }

        write_it(&mut f, "hello world");
        write_it(&mut f, "goodbye world");
    } else {
        println!("Reading from {}", path);
        let mut f = File::open(&Path::new(path)).unwrap();

        fn read_it<R>(r: &mut R) -> String where R: Reader {
            let mut z = ZlibDecoder::new(ByRefReader::by_ref(r));
            z.read_to_string().unwrap()

        }

        println!("{}", read_it(&mut f));
        println!("{}", read_it(&mut f));
    }
}
```

This *does* work for writing - I see the Zlib header get repeated twice in the output file. However, it **does not** work when reading. It looks like `reader::ZlibDecoder` might consume all the way to the end of the underlying `Reader`. This could potentially be a bug or an oversight in the `flate2` library. A few minutes of staring at [the source](https://github.com/alexcrichton/flate2-rs/blob/6430b38674655039cbe63e5b64320ff9afec45b8/src/raw.rs#L184-L235) hasn't shown anything obvious though.

**Edit**

Here's a terrible hack that "works" though:

```
fn read_it<R>(r: &mut R) -> String where R: Reader {
    let mut z = ZlibDecoder::new_with_buf(ByRefReader::by_ref(r), Vec::with_capacity(1));
    z.read_to_string().unwrap()
}

println!("{}", read_it(&mut f));
f.seek(-1, std::old_io::SeekStyle::SeekCur);
println!("{}", read_it(&mut f));
```

The problem arises because flate2 is [a bit greedy in how it reads from the reader](https://github.com/alexcrichton/flate2-rs/blob/6430b38674655039cbe63e5b64320ff9afec45b8/src/raw.rs#L196). It always tries to fill its own internal buffer as much as it can, even if some of that data isn't going to be read. This *terrible, nasty* hack causes it to only ever read a single byte at a time. Thus, you can rewind one byte at the end and start again.

A longer-term solution is probably to add an accessor for [`total_in`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/flate2-rs/blob/6430b38674655039cbe63e5b64320ff9afec45b8/miniz-sys/lib.rs#L28) up to [`Stream`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/flate2-rs/blob/6430b38674655039cbe63e5b64320ff9afec45b8/src/raw.rs#L155) and then up until you get to `ZlibDecoder`.

Comment: A terrible nasty hack is just what the doctor ordered!